# Calculating distances and relationships between point land line vector layers using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, distance, line

I have two vector layers. One lines and the other points.

I am trying to find  how far dots are apart from lanes, on average?

I am thinking about setting a buffer around the lines, and finding how many points would be in that buffer, but may be there are other simpler functions in QGIS

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the GRASS tool **v.net.connect** to create the nearest line from each point. You can access this from the *Processing Toolbox*.

---

**Example:**

1. Simple point and line layers

   [image: Points and lines]
2. Run the said tool:

   [image: v.net.connect]
3. Hopefully, it will output another line layer containing lines connecting each point to its nearest line (network):

   [image: Connected points to lines]
4. Use the **Field Calculator** on the output layer, create a new field and use the expression `$length` to calculate the length of each line in your output layer, including those which connects the point.