# Minimum distance from a point to nearest line among multiple lines shapefile

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I am new to QGIS. I am looking for any plugin or any manual method in QGIS for finding minimum distance (perpendicular distance) from a point which is part of one shapefile to nearest line among many lines which is part of another shapefile.

MMQGIS is not useful for this purpose.

Comment: Could this post and answer help? [Calculating distances and relationships between point and line vector layers using QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224886/calculating-distances-and-relationships-between-point-land-line-vector-layers-us)

Comment: Thanks kazuhito for reply. I used the method suggested by you. I am getting minimum distance ( perpendicular distance) from points which are part of one shape file to nearest line among many lines which is part of another shape file. But there is one problem. I am not identifying from the attribute table that which lengh is belong to which point. In attribute table, there 32 lengh values for 32 points w.r.t nearest line. Is there any method to identify which length value is belong to which point.

Comment: With your suggestion, I am able to corelate particular length data with particular point. But I am also want to know that lengh data belong to which line. In lines shape file, I have two fields 1. ID 2. Time.

Comment: . It is not working for my case. When I am using v.net.connect command new shape file is created which is containing cat, ID , time field and I added length field using field calculator. ID & Time field for existing lines are same as line shape file. However new line created from point to nearest line has null value for ID & Time field. It has only cat & length value. When I am doing joints by location method between line shape file & network file , I am getting details of only about old lines of line shape file and not getting any about new line created between points and nearest line.

Comment: I am getting length (minimum distance) between points and nearest lines w.r.t to points, but not able to corelate particular lengh value with respective line.

Comment: Thanks for your continuous support. I am able to corelate particular length value with particular point using join by location function. But not able to corelate particular length value with particular line.

Comment: @Jitendra : Can you edit your question here reflecting the new information you are giving in the multiple duplicates [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228868/minimum-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line-among-multiple-lines-shape-file) and [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229265/minimum-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line-among-multiple-lines-shape-file) and in the comments? It would be easier for users to answer.

Answer (score 5):

Based on the information in your comments and duplicates [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229265/minimum-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line-among-multiple-lines-shape-file) and [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228868/minimum-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line-among-multiple-lines-shape-file), I'd like to suggest the following. This has been done using the '*Processing Toolbox*' in QGIS which allows you to use GRASS algorithms easily within QGIS -

Add two columns to the point layer, one for distance(*distance*) and the other for the Line ID(*id_line*). When using **v.distance**, you can specify multiple options in *'upload'* by entering the values separated by commas. Try doing something like this -

[image]

The *'dist'* will upload the minimum distance to the column *'distance'* and *'to_attr'* lets you specify a particular column name from your line layer to be uploaded to *'id_line'*.

Running this would give you your desired output in the layer saved in **Nearest**, a copy of your point layer with the columns '*distance*' and '*id_line*' populated.

Your result would something like this -

[image]

Alternately, if your processing toolbox doesn't show '*v.distance*' you can use the GRASS shell directly and execute the command for *v.distance* as follows -

```
v.distance from=<point layer> to=<line layer> upload=dist,to_attr to_column=<column containing id> column=distance,id_line
```

Refer the man page of [v.distance](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/v.distance.html) or just type `v.distance --help` in the shell for more options.

Comment: Thanks for reply. v.distance commnd is not showing/opening in processing toolbox.  Is there any settings required for same?

Comment: Can you share which version of QGIS you are using?

Comment: You can check under the options of Processing whether the GRASS provider is activated or not.

Comment: QGIS version 2.14

Comment: Do you have access to other GRASS algorithms in Processing? It may be that your provider is not activated. Which version of GRASS is installed?

Comment: Grass 7 has been installed. Yes I am able to use v.net.connect command from processing toolbox.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. 
You mentioned using v.distance in one of your other [questions](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/229265/minimum-distance-from-points-to-nearest-line-among-multiple-lines-shape-file). Can you share how were you using it then?

Comment: I am using v.distance command with opening QGIS desktop with GRASS program. Then plugin shows grass menu.  Then set the grass mapset and open grass module from grass menu in plugin menu.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223767/activating-missing-standard-grass-utilities-in-qgis-processing-toolbox.  This link also describes same problem like mine.

Comment: I'd strongly encourage you to either reinstall the latest version of QGIS/GRASS or fix the problem with the Processing toolbox. It would make it much easier for you to use the GRASS algorithms within QGIS and also make it easier to automate multiple steps.

Comment: In the meanwhile, have a look at my updated answer which should work for you using the GRASS shell.

Comment: Thanks Nash for your valuable guidance. I have installed QGIS 2.18.3 and I am getting desired result now. I think there is some problem in QGIS 2.14.8 in which I am working.

Comment: Now  I am getting minimum distance between points and lines. But how can I know that a point is located to right side of line or left side of line. Distance field is giving absolute value so I can't able to identify point location w.r.t line (Right Or left)

Comment: Add another column and use an extra _upload_ option '**to_x**' when using _v.distance_. It would give you the x-coordinate of the intersecting point on the line. Now, you can use field calculator and calculate the difference between the x-coordinate of your point and intersecting x-coordinate. If the result is negative the point is on the left, if it is positive the point is on the right.

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Thanks Nash. Yes the method , suggested by you, is working fine.

Comment: nach, after running the tool -no layer added to the map. the default is "save to temporary file"-where i can find the nearest new layer?